# All possible combinations of subvalues in a list

Tags: python

I'm working on how to generate all possible combinations of subvalues in a list.

For instance if I have the list: `['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']`, I'm trying to generate a matrix of all possible combinations of values that do not include the first element changing while also appending the first element to the end of the list.

Desired output:

```
['abc','def','ghi','jkl','abc']
['abc','def','jkl','ghi','abc']
['abc','ghi','def','jkl','abc']
['abc','ghi','jkl','def','abc']
['abc','jkl','ghi','def','abc']
['abc','jkl','def','ghi','abc']
```

I tried working with itertools but I'm relatively new to the package. It seems to work for each individual character of the list, but not the value as a whole:

Current code:

```
buildings=['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
for t in itertools.product(*buildings):
    print(t)
```

Current Output:

```
('a', 'd', 'g', 'j')
('a', 'd', 'g', 'k')
('a', 'd', 'g', 'l')
('a', 'd', 'h', 'j')
and so on
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate all permutations of a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `itertools.permutations` instead for your purpose:

```
from itertools import permutations
first, *rest = buildings
for p in permutations(rest):
    print([first, *p, first])
```

This outputs:

```
['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'abc']
['abc', 'def', 'jkl', 'ghi', 'abc']
['abc', 'ghi', 'def', 'jkl', 'abc']
['abc', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'def', 'abc']
['abc', 'jkl', 'def', 'ghi', 'abc']
['abc', 'jkl', 'ghi', 'def', 'abc']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
 tab = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
 print(list(itertools.permutations(tab,len(tab))))
```

> ```
>  [('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'), ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'), ('abc',
>  'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'), ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'), ('abc', 'def',
>  'ghi', 'jkl'), ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'), ('abc', 'def', 'ghi',
>  'jkl'), ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'), ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'),
>  ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'), ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'), ('abc',
>  'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'), ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'), ('abc', 'def',
>  'ghi', 'jkl'), ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'), ('abc', 'def', 'ghi',
>  'jkl'), ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'), ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'),
>  ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'), ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'), ('abc',
>  'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'), ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'), ('abc', 'def',
>  'ghi', 'jkl'), ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl')]
> ```